# How to prevent spring boot from logging both into specified file and catalina.out

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, logback

I'm working in a spring-boot project (version 1.5.1) and using logback. My `application.properties` has the following log settings:

```
logging.level.=info
logging.level.org.acme.myapp=info
logging.file=${catalina.home}/logs/AppLogFile.log
```

When the application logs something this is written to the specified `AppLogFile.log` and also to `catalina.out`:

```
==> AppLogFile.log <==
2017-04-13 13:37:33.102 DEBUG 4646 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-25] c.l.c.c.controller.IndexPage             : isAllowedToSeeContent: Homebase: MOCKBASE

==> catalina.out <==
2017-04-13 13:37:33.102 DEBUG 4646 --- [io-8080-exec-25] c.l.c.c.controller.IndexPage             : isAllowedToSeeContent: Homebase: MOCKBASE

==> AppLogFile.log <==
2017-04-13 13:37:33.108 DEBUG 4646 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-25] c.l.c.c.controller.MedlistService        : MedlistService::isControlDay 2017-04-13, true

==> catalina.out <==
2017-04-13 13:37:33.108 DEBUG 4646 --- [io-8080-exec-25] c.l.c.c.controller.MedlistService        : MedlistService::isControlDay 2017-04-13, true
```

This seems to be `additivity` Problem. Is it really necessary to provide logback.xml like mentioned in here: [howto-configure-logback-for-logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging)?
Or is there a more direct way?

---

*Update:*

Even if I follow the recommendation from the [howto](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging-fileonly) and add a `logback-spring.xml` to my classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}" />    
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I get the following errors (en masse):

```
17:50:01.267 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [LOGGING_patternLevel] threw NamingException with message: Name [LOGGING_patternLevel] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [LOGGING_patternLevel].. Returning null.
17:50:01.267 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/LOGGING_patternlevel]
```

---

Setting `logging.pattern.console=` to an empty string, seems to do the trick - BUT is this really the right solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the target tomcat is NOT under my control and my application is not the only one on the server, I've decided to disable the console logging by setting the `logging.pattern.console=` to an empty string.

---

The answer from [Olaf Kock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391599/how-to-prevent-spring-boot-from-logging-both-into-specified-file-and-catalina-ou/43391675#43391675), I'm sure, is also valid, see the [Considerations for production usage](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Console) paragraph - but I have to admit I failed to get it working - Therefor I could not test it :(

Answer (score 0):

Does your tomcat's `conf/logging.properties` contain the following line?

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

This is part of the default package. Remove the ConsoleHandler entry from it.

Comment: Yes, but just removing the ConsoleHandler does not have an effect. I've tried all 3 combinations -

`handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, ..., 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler` -
`.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler`
- - -
`grep -r isControlDay`
`catalina.out: 18:05:29.640 ... isControlDay 2017-04-13, true`
`MyAppLog.log: 18:05:29.640 ... isControlDay 2017-04-13, true`
---
Although this is a recommendation in the tomcat docu. -
But I would prefer to change it for my app only and not on the whole system.

Comment: You'll need to restart after this. Your app does not write to catalina.out. Tomcat pipes everything that's directed to stdout into catalina.out - you can either change this, or stop writing to stdout (which might be done by your own logging).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! But just changing `.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` to `.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler` has no effect. I've tried it with an freshly unpacked tomcat (8.5.12) and a simple hello world example. Tomcat was restarted. Log is printed to both `hello.log` and `catalina.out`. I've also checked that tomcat is using the correct properties file. It seems there is still something missing.